# Stored MySQL function not being found

Tags: php, mysql

Getting this error when I try to run this script. I'm creating the function before I call it so I'm not sure why it would return the fact that it does not exist.

Error:

> FUNCTION db.fn_distance_cosine does not exist[]

Also, same script is running fine locally but am having this problem on another machine.

Thoughts?

Thanks!

```
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die ('Error connecting to mysql'); //remote
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('db', $con); //remote

if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use selected database : ' . mysql_error());
} 

$lat = $_GET["lat"];
$lon = $_GET["lon"];
$rows = array();

$establishFunction = mysql_query("DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS fn_distance_cosine;
CREATE FUNCTION fn_distance_cosine (
    latitude_1 DOUBLE,
    longitude_1 DOUBLE,
    latitude_2 DOUBLE,
    longitude_2 DOUBLE
)
RETURNS DOUBLE
DETERMINISTIC
SQL SECURITY INVOKER
RETURN ACOS(
      SIN(RADIANS(latitude_1)) * SIN(RADIANS(latitude_2))
      + COS(RADIANS(latitude_1)) * COS(RADIANS(latitude_2))
      * COS(RADIANS(longitude_2 - longitude_1))
    ) * 3956.547;
");

mysql_query("SET @input_lat :=" . $lat . ";");
mysql_query("SET @input_lon :=" . $lon . ";");

mysql_query("SET @max_latitude := @input_lat + DEGREES(50.0/3956.547);");
mysql_query("SET @min_latitude := @input_lat - DEGREES(50.0/3956.547);");
mysql_query("SET @max_longitude := @input_lon + DEGREES(50.0/3956.547/COS(RADIANS(@input_lat)));");
mysql_query("SET @min_longitude := @input_lon - DEGREES(50.0/3956.547/COS(RADIANS(@input_lat)));");

if($result = mysql_query("SELECT
      *,
      fn_distance_cosine(lat, lon, @input_lat, @input_lon) AS distance_in_miles,
      COUNT(*) AS store_number_count
    FROM stores
    JOIN items_stores
    ON stores.store_number=items_stores.store_number
    WHERE `lat` BETWEEN @min_latitude AND @max_latitude
      AND `lon` BETWEEN @min_longitude AND @max_longitude
    GROUP BY stores.store_code
    HAVING store_code_count > 1
    ORDER BY distance_in_miles
    LIMIT 10;
    ")){  
        while ($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $rows[] = $r;
    }
}else{
    //failed.
    echo (mysql_error ());
}

print json_encode($rows);

mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My db user did not have the correct permissions to store a procedure.

Comment: hi in my case i am assuming the same as my function can be executed from client like query browser or Navicat but not through the web . will you please mention the permission/s  name